# Figure centered (horizontally and vertically) + subsection on same page

Tags: graphics, floats, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I want to center my figure (horizontally and vertically). I have a subesction that I want to keep on the same page (at the top), but it is "pushed" on the next page. I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{cleveref} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,fixltx2e} 
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} 
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{bm} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\linespread{1.5} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subfig} 
\newcommand\inclfig[1]{% \includegraphics[width=120mm]{#1}}
```

and in the document:

```
\subsection{Subsection 1}

\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics{Pictures/picture1.png}
\caption{Caption 1}
\floatfoot{Own illustration}
\label{fig:Label 1}
\end{figure}
```

Please help :)

Comment: `[p]` means put it on a page with just floats. Sounds like you want `[htp]` to allow `h` so it comes under the heading

Comment: Hi David. Just tried. Same result as with [p]. The title/subsection is pushed to the next page.

Comment: every question really should have a complete document that demonstrates the effect, the latex float algorithm has several parameters, and depends on the size of the float, other floats on the same page, the height of the page etc, none of which we can see at all. But see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017

Comment: These are the packages and floats that I am using: